Spring Security context is thread session?
When I was reviewing the debugging project, the previous HTTP request set Spring Security context and redirect, while the next redirected request can directly obtain authentication. In other modules, new HTTP requests cannot be directly obtained. May I ask if Spring Security context is based on request response threading mode or session mode?
The security context strategy for this project is:
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(TransmittableThreadLocalSecurityContextHolderStrategy.class.getName());

Is this related to this setting?
I tried using testing tools such as Postman, but couldn't simulate it, while in the browser, I was able to redirect the above situation.
